# Find and push results in two objects being pushed into the array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When clicking on the Test button below, 2 copies of the object are pushed into the array.

Can anyone explain why this happens? I only expected 1 object.

```js
class Testing extends React.Component {
    state = {
        things: []
    }

    test = () => {
        this.setState(prevState => {
            const things = [...prevState.things];

            things.find(x => x.id === '39cc413f-a25c-409d-ad09-05df5b4b28b6')['stats'].push({
                mana: 100,
                health: 1
            });

            return { things};
        });
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        this.setState({
            things: this.state.things.concat({
                id: '39cc413f-a25c-409d-ad09-05df5b4b28b6',
                stats: [],
                enemies: []
            })
        });
    }

    render() {
        const { things } = this.state;

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <button type="button" onClick={this.test}>Test</button>
                <br />
                {things.map((thing, i) => <div key={i}>{JSON.stringify(thing)}</div>)}
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<React.StrictMode>
  <Testing />
</React.StrictMode>, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: I only see one being pushed, see snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are using strict mode. React in many cases has state callbacks fire twice in order to catch state management mistakes that can occur in production.

> It's specifically the callback argument to this.setState that is run twice - the first result is thrown away, and the second one used. This should make no difference, but does here because the underlying state is being mutated: things is only a shallow copy of prevState.things, so using .find and then mutating the found object causes the apparent double-update. - Robin Zigmond

See:

[GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12856)

[React Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html)

You can deep copy the array easily (not necessarily performant) by using JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(thingy)) as seen below.

[also added error handling if the id doesn't exist.]

```js
class Testing extends React.Component {
    state = {
      things: []
    }

    test = () => {
      this.setState(prevState => {
        console.log(prevState)
        let things = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(prevState.things));

        const index = prevState.things.findIndex(x => x.id === '39cc413f-a25c-409d-ad09-05df5b4b28b6');

        if (index !== -1) {
          let statsCopy = [...things[index].stats, {
            mana: 100,
            health: 1
          }];
          //console.log(statsCopy)
          things[index]["stats"] = [...statsCopy];

          return {
            ...prevState,
            things: [...things]
          }
        }
        return {
          ...prevState
        }

      });
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
      this.setState({
        things: this.state.things.concat({
          id: '39cc413f-a25c-409d-ad09-05df5b4b28b6',
          stats: [],
          enemies: []
        })
      });
    }

    render() {
        const {
          things
        } = this.state;

        return ( <
          React.Fragment >
          <
          button type = "button"
          onClick = {
            this.test
          } > Test < /button> <
          br / > {
            things.map((thing, i) => < div key = {
                i
              } > {
                JSON.stringify(thing)
              } < /div>)} < /
              React.Fragment >
            );
          }
        }

        ReactDOM.render( <
            React.StrictMode >
            <
            Testing / >
            <
            /React.StrictMode>, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: Well spotted that this is the source of the issue - it's worth pointing out exactly why, and what bug in the OP's code is being highlighted. It's specifically the callback argument to `this.setState` that is run twice - the first result is thrown away, and the second one used. This should make no difference, but does here because the underlying state is being mutated: `things` is only a shallow copy of `prevState.things`, so using `.find` and then mutating the found object causes the apparent double-update. It might be worth explaining to the OP how to avoid this by updating immutably.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and example. I landed up using immer because it was a bit easier than having to shadow copy nested arrays. Seems faster too.

Comment: @SeanThorburn Interesting, I had never heard of immer before. Always glad to hear about new technologies (well maybe not "new.") Thank you for commenting how you ended up solving the problem as well.